# Mathematical set symbols in HTML

Tags: html

I wanted to put a bar over my variable such as not(x) and also some set symbols in my web page? How do I incorporate that in my html page.

Answer (score 6):

For the set symbols, you ought to use [unicode HTML entities](http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/cgi-bin/unicode.pl.cgi?start=2200&end=22FF).

For the line over a variable (p), I'd rather use an alternate symbol for not, such as:
¬p (`&#x00AC;p`)

You may also, as a commenter pointed out, use the [combining diacritical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_diacritical_mark) unicode HTML entity like so:
p̅ (`p&#x0305;`)

Lastly, you may use one of the CSS methods provided.

Comment: Those are great for the symbols but how about the bar?

Comment: For a bar you could use the combining diacritic 0x0305 (see http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf)

Comment: Very cool Paul; I didn't know about this. Added to my answer.

Comment: @Dominic - for what it's worth, I'm looking at it right now in Google Chrome.

Comment: I'd rather track down a tool designed to enter mathematical symbols and then use straight Unicode rather than entities. It will result in more readable source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="text-decoration: overline">X</div>
```